# Would a duel model between Khadors' Sorcha and Circles' Kaya seem realistic?

Tags: warmachine, hordes

It's for a model painting competition but I don't know if it fits in with any fluff... Opinions? O.o

Comment: Asking for opinions isn't really how this site works, I'm afraid.  Could you turn this into a more definitively-answerable question?

Answer (score 1):

I will interpret the question as, is there anything in the game rules that would preclude modeling these two figures in combat with each other.

I have not played this one but given my understanding of what's allowed and what's not from various codex-based miniatures games this seems like a plausible pairing. Sorcha is a warcaster (https://battlecollege.wikispaces.com/Sorscha) and Kaya is a warlock (https://battlecollege.wikispaces.com/mkiiKaya) from armies that can and will clash.

You can find in published blogs first person accounts of battles involving both personalities, supporting the view that the two of them actually meeting in close quarters could happen.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, this would be a fight that could happen in the lore. I haven't read the WarMachine books, but the in-game fluff puts Khador and Circle at odds. Those two armies are pretty good matches for each other.